# Generalize Jensen's Integral Inequality to the product of two functions

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral, jensen-inequality

Let $E$ be a measurable set with $m(E)>0$.

Let $f$, $\gamma$ be two measurable, real-valued function which are finite a.e. on $E$ with $f, \gamma$ and $f\cdot \gamma$ all integrable.

Assume $\gamma\geq 0$ and $\int_{E}\gamma>0$. Then if $\phi$ is a convex function on an open interval $(a,b)$ containing the range of $f$, then we have

$\phi\Big(\dfrac{\int_{E}f\cdot\gamma}{\int_{E}\gamma}\Big)\leq\Big(\dfrac{\int_{E}\phi(f)\cdot\gamma}{\int_{E}\gamma}\Big)$

I am trying to modify the proof of the simpler version (the one with only $f$) of Jensen's inequality to this more general version, but I don't really know how to deal with the new function $\gamma$.

Any hints or detailed explanations are really appreciated!!

${\bf Edit\  1:}$

I got some but still limited development.

To make things simpler, I assume $\phi$ has $1^{st}$ derivative, and assume $\int_{E}\gamma=1$

As $\phi$ is convex, for each $a$, we have $\phi(y)>(y-a)\phi'(a)+\phi(a)$

so in particular, as $\gamma\geq 0$, we have

$\int \phi\big(f(x)\big)\cdot\gamma(x)dx\geq\int\big[(f(x)-a)\phi'(a)+\phi(a)\big]\gamma(x)dx=\int \big(f(x)-a\big)\gamma(x)dx\times \phi'(a)+\phi(a)$

Now, let $a=\int f(x)\cdot\gamma(x)dx$, we will have $\int \big(f(x)-a\big)\gamma(x)dx=0$ and we are done in this simple case.

In a general case, a convex function on the real line has only right derivative, and thus we have $\phi(y)>(y-a)\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h}+\phi(a)$, so with the complicated notation, our proof is still okay.

However, how do I expand this case to the case where $\int_{E}\gamma$ is not 1?

$\textbf{My Completed Proof:}$

Okay, I think I proved it.

To make things simpler, let $\int_{E}\gamma=b\geq 0$ and suppose $\phi(x)$ has the first derivative.

As $\phi$ is convex, for each $a$, we have $$\phi(y)>(y-a)\phi'(a)+\phi(a)$$

So in particular, as $\gamma\geq 0$, we have:

$\dfrac{\int_{E}\phi(f(x))\gamma(x)dx}{b}\geq\dfrac{\int_{E} [(f(x)-a)\phi'(a)+\phi(a)]\gamma(x)dx}{b}=\dfrac{\phi'(a)}{b}\int_{E}f(x)\gamma(x)dx-a\phi'(a)+\phi(a)$

Now, let $a=\dfrac{\int_{E}f(x)\gamma(x)dx}{b}$, the first two summands of the above equation will be killed, and we get what we want.

So in general case, convex function has only right derivatives, so we have $$\phi(y)>(y-a)\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h}+\phi(a)$$

By letting $F(a)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\dfrac{\phi(a+h)-\phi(a)}{h}$ our proof is still valid, since $F(a)$ will be killed in the end as what happened to $\phi'(x)$, then we are done.

Is my proof okay here? Feel free to point out my mistake or better proof!

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you define $P(A) = \dfrac{1}{\int_E \gamma} \int_{A \cap E} \gamma$ so that $P$ is a probability measure and what you want to prove is just Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @WillM. I haven't learnt materials about probability measure, would you mind making it more specific?

Comment: I am confused, do you know or not know about Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @WillM. My professor only talks about Jensen's Inequality in the context of Lebesgue Integral, without talking about probability measure. So... I don't know whether I know or do not know Jensen's inequality...

Comment: Jensen's inequality only holds in probability spaces. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the answer is in my post, $\textbf{ My Completed Proof}$ part. Only three minor points need to be added.

Firstly, in the third line of my proof, we need to comment that $a$ in is the domain of $\phi$.

Secondly, in the sixth line, we need to note that $\phi(f(x))$ makes sense since by hypothesis, the domain of $\phi$ contains the range of $f(x)$.

Finally, $a=\dfrac{\int_{E}f(x)\gamma(x)dx}{b}$ makes sense because $\gamma\geq 0$, so we can enlarge or reduce $f$ to its max or min so that $a$ is in the range of $f(x)$.

With all those details added, the proof in my post is complete.